JDBC sink connector failed - Unknown Magic Byte
I use Kafka docker-compose stack. Confluent 7.7.0
and I want to use JDBC sink (confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc)
my source connector is debezium/debezium-connector-postgresql
and I faced with this error:
Failed to deserialize data for topic dev_internal.public.constant_wits to Avro
source.json
{
        "name": "source",
        "config": {
                "topic.prefix": "dev_internal",
                "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
                "database.hostname": "postgres",
                "database.port": "5432",
                "database.user": "*****",
                "database.password": "******",
                "database.dbname": "internal",
                "slot.name": "internal",
                "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
                "publication.name": "publication_debezium",
                "transforms": "unwrap",
                "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
                "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
                "table.exclude.list": "public.django_migrations"
        }
}

my sink.json:
{
    "name":"sink",
    "config":{
        "auto.create":"false",
        "auto.evolve":"false",
        "connection.password":"<PASSWORD>",
        "connection.url":"<JDBC_URL>",
        "connection.user":"<USER>",
        "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "delete.enabled":"true",
        "header.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.SimpleHeaderConverter",
        "insert.mode":"upsert",
        "key.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "key.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://schema-registry:8081",
        "max.retries":"10",
        "pk.fields":"id"
        "pk.mode":"record_key",
        "tasks.max":"1",
        "topics.regex":"dev_internal.(?!public.django_session)(?:.*)",
        "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://schema-registry:8081",
        "transforms":"dropTopicPrefix,UpdatedTimestamp",
        "transforms.dropTopicPrefix.regex":"dev_internal.public(.*)",
        "transforms.dropTopicPrefix.replacement":"$1",
        "transforms.dropTopicPrefix.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
        "transforms.UpdatedAtTimestamp.field":"updated_at",
        "transforms.UpdatedAtTimestamp.format":"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'",
        "transforms.UpdatedAtTimestamp.target.type":"Timestamp",
        "transforms.UpdatedAtTimestamp.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
        ....
    }
}

error:
ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=dev_internal_sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:244)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:166)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:531)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:509)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:345)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:243)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:212)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:229)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:284)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:237)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
 Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to deserialize data for topic dev_internal.public.constant_wits to Avro:
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:148)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$4(WorkerSinkTask.java:531)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:224)
        ... 14 more
 Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.getByteBuffer(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java:600)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.<init>(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:390)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserializeWithSchemaAndVersion(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:264)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter$Deserializer.deserialize(AvroConverter.java:199)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(


You've not shown what converter settings the Debezium connector is using, but the sink is failing since the data is not Avro. Please try to confirm you can consume the data with kafka-avro-console-consumer
